# Не получается установить reCaptcha на сайт

Tags: fetch, recaptcha

Проблема в том, что handle.php не получает значение из $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].

Код запроса:

```
register.addEventListener('submit', function (e){
e.preventDefault();

let body = {
    method: 'reg',
    login: this.querySelector(".reg__login").value,
    pass: this.querySelector(".reg__pass").value,
    pass2: this.querySelector(".reg__pass2").value,
    email: this.querySelector(".reg__email").value,
};

fetch('handle.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then((data) => {

// обработка результата

});
});
```

Код handle.php (начало):

```
    <?php
require ('vendor/autoload.php');
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);

if ($request['method'] == 'reg')
    // регистрация нового юзера
{
    try {
        $objReg = new \Jumpers\Reg($request['login'], $request['pass'], $request['pass2'], $request['email'], $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        var_dump('капча:' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
```

var_dump выводит пустую строку.

Comment: Если уж вы отправили JSON-объект вместо формы с капчей, то, очевидно, в `$_POST` ничего и никак появиться не может

Comment: @andreymal Как отправить одновременно и то и другое?